# MCU SPI in Master mode with Software slave management enabled, Slave is a third party zigbee device which expects its nSSL to be driven externally

Tags: embedded, spi, stm32ldiscovery

I am using my MCU (STM32L486) as the master (SPI) and a zigbee peripheral is the slave device. Currently the master is configured (SSM = 1, SSI = 1) with Software Slave management.
As the slave device expects its ChipSelect to be driven low and high respectively. I understand there will be a need for a GPIO to be used for this purpose.
The pin pack for SPI operation used is (SCK(PA5),MOSI(PA7), MISO(PA6) and NSS(PA4)).
I am confused on the usage of NSS pin.
Since the Master SPI is configured as Software Slave managed, Can i use this (PA4)pin to drive the Slave SSL signal or i cannot use this pin at all.
As the reference manual suggests
[image]
but the notes in the below section (highlighted yellow)
[image]
suggests that both the master and slave has to be handled internally.

Does it mean i cant have the above configuration?, where
1. Master SSL is Software managed.
2. Slave expects its SSL line to be asserted/deasserted externally.

Please provide your insight. I am working on an already written code. There are some issues in the product and i am trying to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the same question in st community forum.
[Response From ST community](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000AAJd64SQD/stm32l486-mcu-used-as-master-spi-zigbee-device-as-slave-what-configuration-of-ssm-and-ssi-should-i-be-using?t=1546972075654)
They have replied back by saying as long as i dont configure the SSL(PA4) as an alternate function pin, i can use it to drive the slave.